# C++ - Starting paraller instances of an executable from a C++ code

Tags: parallel-computing, c++, mpi

Can I start parallel run of LAMMPS from inside a C++ code. Is it possible to compile my code and then do mpirun with my compiled code. I also have one system command inside the code, which starts parallel instances of LAMMPS with mpirun.

Comment: This should be possible in principle. Do you have a deeper question?

Comment: @BillBarth Yeah it should be possible but it is not working. My code looks like this:                                                                                                                                   Main(){ .....MPI_BARRIER                                                                     If(id of processor = 0 ) then do system (mpirun -np 16 -f {Nodelist} ./lammps)}}. This is happenning in main and I am submitting my job as         mpirun -np 16 ./a.out, where a.out is exe

Comment: You can't run `mpirun` from a job that is already running in parallel. If you run `mpirun -np 16 ./a.out`, then you already have 16 instances of `main()` running, so all you need to do is calling the LAMMPS executable directly from each of these instances of `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://github.com/jeffhammond/HPCInfo/blob/master/docs/LAMMPS.mediawiki and https://github.com/awlange/lammps_ensembles. We did exactly this for the purpose of umbrella sampling etc.

Interface to PLUMED worked, among other things.